# Блокировка при insert в партицию

Tags: plsql, insert, oracle12c, delete

Если идет вставка данных в определенную партицию таблицы, что при этом блокируется (вся таблица)?

То есть можно ли одновременно вставлять данные в одну партицию и удалять из другой?

Comment: В общем случае, без partition клаузы вся таблица, а с ней - партиция.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При вставке в Oracle не нужно беспокоиться о блокировке таблиц. По умолчанию Oracle блокирует только вставляемую, обновляемую или удаляемую строку, а также блокировку, предотвращающую операции DDL во время выполнения операции DML.

Oracle использует блокировку на уровне строк и не переводит их случайным образом в блокировки таблиц. Поскольку INSERT по определению создают новые строки, они не могут блокировать друг друга.

Comment: А можно ссылку на источник? Везде пишут по - разному, тут, например: https://olegon.ru/showthread.php?t=25247

Comment: @АнатолийЭрнст [docs.oracle.com](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Automatic-Locks-in-DML-Operations.html#GUID-3D57596F-8B73-4C80-8F4D-79A12F781EFD)
ссылка как раз на раздел документации описывающий автоматическую блокировку. Так же таблицы можно блокировать или нет мануально.